# JAVA, Jersy POST-ing files to server and GET-ing files from server. Using multiPart

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

import com.itz.passport.authentication.Int3DPassport;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartWriter;

public class UploadFileRestClient {
    private WebResource webResource;
    private Client client;
    private String url = "http://development/server/resources/FileService";

    public UploadFileRestClient() {
        try {
            this.client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
            this.webResource = client.resource(url).path("/file");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ClientResponse upload() {
        try {
            Int3DPassport passportAut = new InPassport();
            String host = "http://development/server";
            String userName = "admin";
            String password = "xxxxx";
            String ticket = IntPassport.getTicket(host, userName, password);
            System.out.println("ticket:::::" + ticket);

            WebResource resource = this.webResource;
            MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
            multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
            FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("photo", new File("D://Documents//Test.txt"));
            multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

            // here Iam getting error, return statement.
            return resource.path("upload"+ticket).type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Iam getting exception at in upload() at return statement. so it going to catch and giving null pointer exception. I have googled for this error com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException and nothing resolved my error. I have added mimepull.jar and jeresey-multipart.jar. Still issue is not solved.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type, multipart/form-data, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at Test.main.UploadFileRestClient.upload(UploadFileRestClient.java:66)
    at Test.main.Main.main(Main.java:38)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type, multipart/form-data, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main.Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

Thanks for help and suggestions.

Comment: You're adding the wrong multipart dependency. You are using Jersey 1.x client. The mulitpart you added is for 2.x You need to add the jersey-multipart 1.x dependency.

Answer (score -1):

your error report has the problem, although if you're new to jersey may seem a little cryptic. Your client currently doesn't know how to map multipart requests.

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type, multipart/form-data, was not found
```

I had to register the mutipart stuff in my ApplicationConfig server definition to get it to work, like;

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() 
{
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
    return resources;
}
```

Reading [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/) should help you sort your issue.

so maybe look at;

```
this.client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
```

and experiment with;

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
```

Comment: The OP is using Jersey 1.x. Look at the package name (com.sun.jersey) in the stack trace.